# Something like `top` for vhosts

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, top

Is there any way of establishing what vhosts are keeping Apache processes busy, in real time?

Ideally I'd like a tool like `top` (or `htop`) that shows me which sites are busiest, or most costly, right now.

Could a tool like this be built on [mod_log_forensic](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_forensic.html), which writes a strict log of when each request starts and ends? It wouldn't give you process IDs or CPU time, only the elapsed time from start to finish, but it might help track down leaky or long-running requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that is dependent on log files has the disadvantage that log entries are only generated once a request is complete.

Apache's [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html) shows the current requests, as they're being processed.

Comment: It's not pretty, but it does tell me what each process ID is processing. Accepting.

Comment: It **is ugly** yes!

Answer (score 1):

Feed your access logs to [apachetop](https://github.com/JeremyJones/Apachetop) and see if that's any good for you. At least apachetop fills in your "See the most busiest site/URL in real time" wish.

Something like `tail -f /var/log/apache2/*access_log | apachetop` should work.

Of course, then there's [logstalgia](https://code.google.com/p/logstalgia/) ... :-)

Comment: Ooh, logstalia is pretty :)

Comment: `apachetop` looks useful, but suffers from the same weakness as any software that relies just on the log files, which is that the standard log format doesn't actually include the vhost name, just the path. I could change the log format, but then it wouldn't be the standard. On my system `mod_log_forensic` includes the `Host:` header, but that's probably because NginX is forwarding it to Apache.